Attempt of proving $\frac{\pi^3}{3^\pi} < 1 $ using simple algebra led to contradictory answer
I am trying to prove $\frac{\pi^3}{3^\pi} < 1 $ using simple algebraic manipulation but it yielded the opposite answer(it yielded greater than 1). Every move I made seems correct and yet it yielded wrong answer. I suspect that there is a gap in my understanding of math but I couldnt find where it is. Here is my working:
$\pi > 3$
$\pi^3 > 3^3$ (raise both to the power of 3)
$\frac{\pi^3}{3^\pi} > \frac{3^3}{3^\pi}$  (divide both side by $3^\pi$)
$\frac{\pi^3}{3^\pi} > (\frac{3}{3})^\frac{3}{\pi}$
$\frac{\pi^3}{3^\pi} > (1)^\frac{3}{\pi}$
since 1 raise to any power is 1, then
$\frac{\pi^3}{3^\pi} > 1 $

$\frac{3^3}{3^\pi} \ne (\frac{3}{3})^\frac{3}{\pi}$

Such problems are easy to solve. Grab a calculator (or go to WolframAlpha), then compute all expressions and check where it goes wrong.

Oh my God..i am very sorry. This is such a silly and obvious mistake. I must have spent 2 hours mulling over this question without realizing it. Thankyou for pointing out the obvious
@MartinR

It is not true that$$\frac{3^3}{3^\pi}=\left(\dfrac33\right)^{\frac3\pi}.$$Instead, we have$$\frac{3^3}{3^\pi}=3^{3-\pi}<1,$$since $3-\pi<0$.

Oh my God..i am very sorry. This is such a silly and obvious mistake. I must have spent 2 hours mulling over this question without realizing it. Thankyou for pointing out the obvious

The wrong step lies between the third and fourth lines, because you cannot "factorize" the powers as you did, i.e. $\frac{x^a}{y^b} \neq \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{x^{a/b}}{y^{a/b}}$.
Nevertheless, you may show easily that $\pi^3 < 3^\pi$ without a calculator with the help of a little bit of calculus. Indeed, this statement is equivalent to $\frac{\ln\pi}{\pi} < \frac{\ln3}{3}$ after taking the logarithm, which will turn out to be true if the function $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x}$ decreases on a range containing the interval $[3,\pi]$. Yet, $f'(x) = \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$ is indeed negative for $x > e$.
